# How to transform my data into this form? Fewer rows, and more columns

Tags: r

I wonder if anyone knows how to transform my data into this ideal form (each SampleID as colnames). Thanks a lot!

My data

```
   SampleId                 miRNA_ID        x
1 TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11R-A38N-13 hsa-let-7a-1 7817.009
2 TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11R-A38N-13 hsa-let-7a-1 5915.546
3 TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11R-A38N-13 hsa-let-7a-1 3632.037
4 TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12R-A38N-13 hsa-let-7a-1 6020.645
5 TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21R-A38N-13 hsa-let-7a-1 7183.899
6 TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A-11R-A38N-13 hsa-let-7a-1 6786.363
```

Ideal form

```
     TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11R-A38N-13   TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11R-A38N-13                            
1     hsa-let-7a-1    7817.009                      5915.546
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy!

```
library(tidyr)

spread(df, SampleId, x)
```

Where `df` is the name of your data frame

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a really easiest way.